# Android do while loop

Tags: android, while-loop

Hi This my second question here.
I have the following table

```
|-----|-------|------|------|
|._id.|..INFO.|.DONE.|.LAST.|
|..1..|...A...|...N..|......|
|..2..|...B...|...Y..|..L...|<--- cursor.moveToPosition((int)_id-1);
|..3..|...C...|...Y..|......|
|..4..|...D...|...Y..|......|
|..5..|...E...|...N..|......|
|..6..|...F...|...N..|......|
|-----|-------|------|------|
```

I use the code:

```
cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{INFO,DONE,LAST},null,null,null,null,null);
cursor.moveToPosition((int)_id-1);
String Yval = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DONE));
do
{
    cursor.moveToNext();
    Yval= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DONE));
}
while (Yval=="Y");
s = Yval;
```

I initially point the cursor to the LAST row I accessed, then I make a loop to go through the values in the DONE column, not stopping if there are Y's in the row of the column. When an N appears in the loop, the loop should stop. 
But it doesn't work. 
Yval never equals "Y". So the cursor does one 'moveToNext' and then exits the loop, because it doesn't read Yval as a "Y".
(I also changed everything to integers. 1 for N, and 0 for Y, but it still didn't work)
So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have to use `equals()` method if you want to compare `Strings`

```
while (Yval.equals("Y"));
```

You should know that:

- `==` tests for reference equality.
- `equals` tests for value equality.

So you want to test if **Yval** `String` has **Y** value so you have to use `equals()` method.

You approach doesn't work bacause:

```
String data = "lorem";
data == "lorem" ==> FALSE
data.equals("lorem") == TRUE
```

Also make sure that your `Cursor` has valid *row* so you need to add to condition also *cursor.moveToNext()* so

```
cursor.moveToNext() && (Yval.equals("Y")
```

also you need to treat `cursor.moveToPosition((int)_id-1)` so add it to condition.

Comment: I want my thread to only continue running in its  service while a shared preference is false. How can I achieve that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235759/after-changing-a-variable-do-i-have-to-restart/35236132?noredirect=1#comment58200727_35236132

Answer (score 3):

I recommend changing a few things:

```
if(cursor.moveToPosition((int) _id - 1)) {
    int doneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DONE);
    String Yval;
    do {
        Yval = cursor.getString(doneIndex);
    } while(Yval.equals("Y") && cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

- You should check if a row exists at position `_id - 1` since the SQLite `_id` is a unique id, not the position of a row in a Cursor.
- You only need to fetch the index of the `DONE` column once, simply store it in a local variable.
- As deceiver mentioned, String are tested with `equals()` and similar methods.
- You need consider what happens if all of the rows are "DONE", then you must stop trying to read the Cursor before an *out of bounds* exception is thrown.

Comment: Yep, thanks Sam. And thanks for the code example. Yep, I just wanted to get it to work first. Next step is exactly as you have said, about when all the rows are done. Thanks again.

Comment: I want my thread to only continue running in its  service while a shared preference is false. How can I achieve that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235759/after-changing-a-variable-do-i-have-to-restart/35236132?noredirect=1#comment58200727_35236132