# After changing a variable, do I have to restart?

Tags: java, android, string, multithreading, performance

I have a long running service, that consists of two threads.

```
//MY SERVICE:

if(userEnabledProcessOne) //Shared preference value that I'm getting from the settings of my app based on a checkbox

    processOneThread.start();

if(userEnabledProcessTwo)

    processTwoThread.start();
```

Basically, I give the user the option to enable/disable these processes with a checkbox.
Now, if the user decides to disable one of the processes **while the service is running**, do I need to restart my service with the updated shared preferences? Like so?

```
//In the settings activity of my app
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // Change shared preferences to make the process enabled

 stopService(myService.class)
 startService(myService.class)

        } if (!isChecked)
            // Change shared preferences to make the process enabled


 stopService(myService.class)
 startService(myService.class)
    }
```

Now that I've changed my shared preferences, do I need to relaunch my service consisting of two threads? Do I need to do anything to the threads? Is this efficient?

Thanks so much,

Ruchir

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, doing that will leeak leak way too much, your Service class runs on a Thread, if you call `stopSelf()` and lets say he is the only run keep the MainThread alive then it will stop leaving the two `Thread`s to play around.

Threads do not depend on the Service, so what you do is you have a `Volatile` `boolean` in your service class like so

```
 private volatile boolean killThreads = false;//guess in your case this
 //flag will be binded to the isChecked of the checkbox or even the 
 //interface method
```

when you want to restart the you toggle killThreads = true; , and now in your implementation of your Threads workloads, what you need to do is if they are in a loop they need to always check killThreads flag if its true its death time if not continue, if not in a loop, still you need to constantly be checking for that flag after every major code line

**Example**

```
//in your Service class
private volatile boolean killThreads = false;
//we have jumped to your thread - i am creating a new instance
while(!killThreads){ //if means if this flag is false keep your loop
//hard code comes here
}
//or if you are not running a loop
//in your run method you can constantly check for this flag like
for(int i =0; i < 100; i++){
   if(killThreads){
      break;//or return if you like
     }
    //rest of the code
 }
 //after the loop you can also check again
 if(killThreads){
    return;
  }
```

just check the flag after a concrete code lines

now in your activity

```
  //In the settings activity of my app
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{
    // Change shared preferences to make the process enabled
   //what you do here is you update killThreads with the isChecked
   //so find a way to bind your bind your Activity to Service class
  //there are tons of example on here
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure what you mean by the volatile Boolean. Can you show me an example so that I can understand better? Thanks so much! ☺

Comment: check my edit and see if its lucid for you @RuchirBaronia , Also i guess if you want to post a question here let it be specific, these stackoverflow users do not like to see questions like these, where there are soo many different ways to achieve it, and you see? so, to have a good experience here. be good sir, and wish you success

Comment: I am not binding anything, because it is running in the background forever. My question is, how will I check after 100 iterations of the for loop? I need to constantly check...

Comment: hmm Sir, try to understand a little, fine, then instead of killThreads flag it should be should be your return value from the sharedPreference which is the boolean, also if you are itereating over 100 values any code lines in the { is executed before } and i know you know that so check the edit again and you will see it does check and terminates.@RuchirBaronia have you understood that sir? also there is an if statement at the end of the for loop so there is a check after the loop

Comment: I understand that thanks, but user may change settings anytime, even after the for loop is done. Then, it won't check, and this code won't work. How can I fix that?

Comment: sir, listen the loop is not for your service is was a demo to say if you have a thread like you have two threads, since i do not know the implementation of your other threads wihich is ProcessOneThread etc etc, i gave you a demo implementation of a thread, now if the user changes it the thread listening to it will die, after you do not have to restart your service all you have to do is bind your activity to the service and start the two threads - to match with your app design.@RuchirBaronia